# Как настроить отображение шрифтов в Opera mini и Dolphin?

Tags: android, html, android-layout, шрифты

Скачал шрифты, написал css код, шрифт правильно отображается и на pc (все браузеры), и на андроид, но кроме Opera mini и Dolphin.  
 Может, нужен какой-то спец. формат?

Код:

```
@font-face {  
    font-family: 'DecorCondensed';  
    src: url('fonts/regular/3C6ehbfN.eot');  
    src: url('fonts/regular/3C6ehbfN.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  
    url('fonts/regular/3C6ehbfN.woff2') format('woff2'),  
    url('fonts/regular/3C6ehbfN.woff') format('woff'),  
    url('fonts/regular/3C6ehbfN.ttf') format('truetype'),  
    url('fonts/regular/3C6ehbfN.svg#DecorCondensed') format('svg');  
    font-weight: normal;  
    font-style: normal;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Opera.mini не поддерживает кастомные шрифты ([link](https://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-web-content-authoring-guidelines/#typography)).